# Why is "find" on OSX having trouble with regex?

Tags: regex, macos, find

```bash
find -E . -type f -iregex ".*Diss.*\.tex" -exec basename {} +
```

or

```bash
find -E . -type f -iregex "(.*/).*Diss.*\.tex" -exec basename {} +
```

finds ALL files with extension `.tex`, but does not limit their names to `Diss*.tex`

Is it OSX malfunctioning, or is the regex wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` pattern matches any 0 or more chars, hence the `Myfile` may appear in any part of the path. See your regex demo:

[image]

You may restrict the `Myfile` to only appear after the last `/` if you replace those `.*` at the end with `[^/]*` matching any 0+ chars other than `/`.

The pattern will look like

```
.*/[^/]*Myfile[^/]*\.tex
```

Here is a [demo of what it will match](https://regex101.com/r/7CvLqB/1/).